# Create dependency property without inheriting off DependencyObject

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I've added a basic auto-property to a class, and I want that property to be set whenever the SelectedItem of a treeview changes. So I add this to a `Resources` somewhere in my XAML:

```
<myns:MyClass x:Key="MyClassResource" MyProperty="{Binding ElementName=treeView, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

but when I try and run this, I get an exception: 'A Binding can only be set on a dependency property'. Now, dependency properties require inheriting off `DependencyObject`, but `MyClass` *already* inherits a class! I don't need all the two-way binding stuff, all I want is that whenever `SelectedItem` changes, the value gets copied into `MyProperty`.

How can I do this in a simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make MyProperty a regular CLR property, the define your binding on your treeView's SelectedItemproperty, setting the binding mode to OneWayToSource, this will cause it to 'push' changes to your MyProperty property on your class.

Comment: @thecoop: this is a frustrating limitation (I would say bug) with bindings. Even if you're binding `OneWayToSource` and the target is read-only, it gives you this error. The only workaround I know of is an attached behavior. Here's the connect issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/WPF/feedback/details/523865/read-only-dependency-properties-does-not-support-onewaytosource-bindings?wa=wsignin1.0